# Getting error while adding dynamic component angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to add component dynamically to my app.

I have a component called **formcontainer**. I want to load different forms within this component according to config.

So i searched on google and tried to add component dynamically, But i am getting console error. **Cannot read property createComponent of undefined.**
`this.includeTemplate` is undefined. According to code error is right, because value is not assign to variable. But examples i am referring did same thing and that is working.

I think i am missing something.

**formcontainer component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';

    import {ActivateAccountComponent} from  '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/activateaccount.ts'


    @Component({
        selector: 'form-container',
        templateUrl: '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/login/template/landingdisplay.html'
    })

    export class FormContainerComponent implements OnInit{

        @ViewChild('includeTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef })  
        private includeTemplate: ViewContainerRef;
        private componentRef:ComponentRef<any>;

        constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

        ngOnInit() : void{          

            let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ActivateAccountComponent);
            this.componentRef = this.includeTemplate.createComponent(componentFactory);
            // this.includeTemplate is undefined

        }       
    }
```

**ActivateAccountComponent**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'activate-account',
    template: `<div class="ActivateAccountContainer"> HI </div>`
})

export class ActivateAccountComponent {

    constructor() {}    
}
```

**landingdisplay.html**

```
<div id="FormContainer" #includeTemplate class="FormContainer ideolveloginform"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to be right. Is your path to landingdisplay.html correct? Try embedding the html in the component and see if it works.

Like this:
template: '<div id="FormContainer" #includeTemplate class="FormContainer ideolveloginform"></div>'

Comment: @JasonLutz ok. I will try that. But template will be bigger than current template. so i kept template in separate file.

Comment: You can put it in a separate template again once you test it out, but I wanted to make sure it works inline first. The template looked right to me, so I thought the problem might've been the path.

Comment: @JasonLutz yes it's working.

Comment: Ok, double-check your path then. Do you need a period before the first slash?

Comment: try to call `createComponent` in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID getting another error. 
**core.umd.js:3064 EXCEPTION: Error in ./ActivateAccountComponent class ActivateAccountComponent - inline template:0:5 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'CD_INIT_VALUE'. Current value: 'ActivateAccountContainer marginlefttwentypx margintoptwentypx marginrighttwentypx marginbottomtwentypx heighthundredpercent'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?**

Comment: @JasonLutz templateUrl worked with ngAfterViewInit, but getting error metion in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MohamedAliRACHID said `ngAfterViewInit` used instead of `ngOnInit` and error mentioned in comment is solved by enclosing dynamic component code into `setTimeout` function.

Here is **formcontainer component**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';

import {ActivateAccountComponent} from  '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/activateaccount.ts'


   @Component({
      selector: 'form-container',
      templateUrl: '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/login/template/landingdisplay.html'
   })

    export class FormContainerComponent implements AfterViewInit{

        @ViewChild('includeTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef })  
        private includeTemplate: ViewContainerRef;
        private componentRef:ComponentRef<any>;

        constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}     

        ngAfterViewInit() : void{

        setTimeout(() => {
            let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ActivateAccountComponent);
            this.componentRef = this.includeTemplate.createComponent(componentFactory);
        }, 1);      
    }       
    }
```